# Grails not downloading latest plugin version from local repo

Tags: maven, grails, nexus

**My setup:**

- I'm using Grails 2.3.8
- I have several private plugins I publish to my local Nexus repository manually via "grails publish-plugin"
- I have several Grails applications that use these plugins
- Distributed development team

**My goal:**

- Able to deploy new versions of my private plugins and have my Grails apps automatically use those latest versions without having to modify their BuildConfig.groovy files
- I know about inline/inplace plugin definitions and that is not what I want

**Possible solutions:**

As I understand it there might be at least two ways of achieving my goal:

1. Deploy snapshot versions of my plugins and have my Grails apps use those snapshot versions (e.g., version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT")
2. Configure my Grails apps's BuildConfig.groovy to use "latest.release" or [Maven version ranges](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges). Examples:

   - compile 'com.mycompany:some-plugin:latest.version'
   - compile 'com.mycompany:some-plugin:[0.1,)'

**The problem:**

The two methods above sort of work.

They both result in the latest version of my plugin to be downloaded, at least initially. However, if I publish a new version of the plugin (be it snapshot or release), re-running "grails run-app" on my Grails applications do not attempt to download/install the newer versions which are available.

I feel like the maven-metadata-*.xml files in my M2_HOME local repo are limiting the versions which are known to exist (even though Nexus has newer versions available).

When I define my Nexus repo using mavenRepo(), do I need to pass in some parameters to tell Grails to always check for new versions on the remote repo and not rely on the local repo?

Graeme's suggestion here does not seem to help either: [Dependencies and lastest.release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045849/dependencies-and-lastest-release)

Any help would be great. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you configured the `updatePolicy` for the repository? See

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#changingDependencies

Section "Aether and SNAPSHOT dependencies". Example:

```
mavenRepo "http://myrepo", {
    updatePolicy "interval:1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2.3.7 and seemed to experience a similar problem.  Using a SNAPSHOT plugin should be what you want during development.  One workaround solution I used was to delete the SNAPSHOT release from Artifactory and then after building a new SNAPSHOT the plugin change was recognized.  I am guessing you are using the Maven build which is now the default you could try switching to the ivy build and see if that helps.  A JIRA should be created if you are able to recreate this.  I believe this is an issue and I do not recall this when working with an older version (2.1.5) and using the ivy build.